# Undefined reference to __mulhi3 when using sprintf() - AVR GCC in Code::Blocks on Windows

Tags: codeblocks, avr, undefined-reference, avr-gcc

I am using Code::Blocks with AVR-GCC toolchain from Microchip (Atmel). I am trying to compile program for `Atmega32`. I get "Undefined reference to `__mulhi3`" when I try to compile program that uses `sprintf()` function. Without this function I get no error. The same program compiled in Atmel Studio or in Code::Blocks under Linux works fine.

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[20];
    sprintf(buf, "Hello %d", 1);

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by default settings of Code::Blocks for `GNU GCC Compiler for AVR` - there are unnecessary include paths to `C:/WinAVR/avr/lib`. You should go to

> Settings → Compiler... → GNU GCC Compiler for AVR → Search directiories → Linker

and clear list of include paths. If the list is not empty, [linker tries to link against wrong version of library.](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1044736#comment-1044736)